# Django validation when creating new instances of models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-validation

I am new to Django and am using the Django Rest Framework tutorial to create web API's.

I have the following models and I have views which use the createAPIView to create new instances of each of these models.

```
class ValidationClass (models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    parameters = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {} - {}'.format(self.id, self.name, self.parameters)

    db = 'qa_suite'

class Test(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    test_group = models.ForeignKey(TestGroup)
    description = models.TextField()
    query_text = models.TextField()
    failure_condition = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(
    ('Error', 'Error'),
    ('Warn', 'Warn')
), default = 'Error')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(
    ('Enabled', 'Enabled'),
    ('Disabled', 'Disabled')
), default = 'Enabled')
    created = models.DateTimeField('Creation Date', auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField('Date last updated', auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.id, self.name)

    db = 'qa_suite'

class TestValidation(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    validation_class = models.ForeignKey(ValidationClass)
    input_parameters = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {} - {}'.format(self.test, self.validation_class, self.input_parameters)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('test', 'validation_class'),)

    db = 'qa_suite'
```

What I would like to do, is make sure that every time a new Test object is created, it is linked to at least one ValidationClass object.
The Test object has a one to many relationship with the ValidationClass object (i.e. one test could have multiple validation class objects linked to it). Because of this, I cannot add a foreign key reference to the validation class object in the model for Test. 
So essentially, what I am looking to do, is each time a new Test object is being created, I want to make sure that a new TestValidation object is also created.

Views:

```
# Post new Validation Class Object to database
class ValidationClassCreateAPI(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ValidationClassSerializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

# Post new Test Validation Object to database
class TestValidationCreateAPI(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TestValidationSerializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

# Post new Test Object to database
class TestCreateAPI(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Database assertions are not available through django ORM. But you can do some checks in code.

You can override `save` method of `Test` and check for your desired conditions there. If conditions were not met, do not perform save operation.

Also you may want to wrap creation of `Test` and `ValidationClass` objects in a `transaction.atomic` block to make sure their creation is performed in [one transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/).

```
from django.db import transaction

def viewfunc(request):
    # This code executes in autocommit mode (Django's default).
    do_stuff()

    with transaction.atomic():
        # This code executes inside a transaction.
        do_more_stuff()
```

Comment: I have added my views used to create these models to this post. Even if I use atomic transactions, how can I enforce that when a new Test Object is created, it must also create a new TestValidation object?

Comment: overriding save method would be the best solution i can think of right now

Comment: Hi  @RajveerParikh if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. I reckon that you did not accept any answers on none of the questions you asked, so I guess you didn't know about it(?). This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.